# Drupal 7 node_save set dates

Tags: drupal-7, nodes

I'm creating nodes automatically from xml, and I need to set the creation dates for them. I tried with

```
<?php 
   ...
   $node->created = $date //<- unix timestamp, $node is my node object
   $node->changed = $other_date; 
   ...
?>
```

but no luck, it sets the current date. 
Any ideas? 
Thanks

-edit-

```
$newNode = (object) NULL;
$newNode->type = 'blog';
$newNode->title = $title;
$newNode->uid = 1;
$newNode->status = 1;
$newNode->comment = 0;
$newNode->moderate = 0;
$newNode->sticky = 0;
$newNode->body['und'][0] = array(
                                'value' => $body,
                                'format' => 'full_html');
$newNode->log      = 'Auto Imported Node';
$newNode->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

// add fields
$newNode->field_description[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $description;
$newNode->field_byline[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $byline;
$newNode->field_small_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $smallimg;
$newNode->field_large_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $largeimg;


// save node
$newNode->created = $pd; // i've tried with commenting this line out, too
$newNode->date = $pd;
node_save($newNode);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work for `$node->created`, but `$node->changed` can't be set with Drupal API.

If you are using `node_submit()` function which uses `strtotime($node->date)` to set `$node->created`, you need to set `$node->date` as a string date.

```php
$node->date = $date_string;
```

Comment: Hmm, I've tried, but it don't works...do you have an idea, why?

Comment: No, I'm not using `node_submit()`, I should? Only `node_save()`

Comment: @ZoltánSeer if you are just using `node_save()`, check your your `$date` variable and show here :)

Comment: And what do you get in “Authored on” field? I tested...http://i.imgur.com/pT1Po.png

Answer (score 0):

@Zoltan: thx, you are right! when i use:

```
$node->date = '2005-05-06 08:17:27';
node_save($node);
```

i get after save:

```
[created] => current timestamp
[changed] => current timestamp
```

but when add line before node_save:

```
$node = node_submit($node);
```

i get after save:

```
[created] => 1115360247
[changed] => current timestamp
```

and on the node page will be displayed "created" date